# Sending money from Coinbase to My Ethereum wallet. It doesn't appear the money

Tags: coinbase

it has been one day, when I pass Ethers from Coinbase to my Ethereum wallet. And I still have 0.00 money. I've checked the address and it's ok.

What is the reason? Thank you.

Comment: Hi there. It's likely that your Wallet hasn't finished syncing the blockchain data. Can you confirm what the latest block it knows about is?

Comment: Sorry Richard i am a beginner, I don't know what do you mean with the latest block...

Answer (score 0):

If you are in doubt that a transaction has happened.

Get the transaction id (transaction hash) from the sending wallet (Coinbase). It looks like 0xc99d008a87cf6faa245314fe914a5a9f8a548d7c92b3fc9ed746b80713f947b7.

Then go to https://etherscan.io

Enter the transaction hash to the search box in the top right corner.

It will give you the transaction details: did it happen, when it did happen, who was the sender, who was the receiver and how much ETH was moved. If EtherScan shows the transaction correctly then it has happened and MyEtherWallet should show your balance.

Link to an example transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdb9e95e9451b5556842ffc397fa30a5fe3f85b92190cf5aae551787f410a6607

Comment: Hello Mikko, in ethersacan.io i realize that appear the transaction, example. It shows the nº of transactions which is 1. value 0.36.

Comment: But in my ethereum wallet still shows 0.00

Comment: The transaction has happened, so it is an issue with your wallet.